# Google Map not showing (Spring, Maven, Thymeleaf, SalesPoint)

Tags: javascript, html, spring, google-maps, thymeleaf

im currently working on a Google Map in a Spring project with Thymeleaf. 
I want to show a map where the User can drag&drop the marker and set the new location. 
But the map is not showing. If I try it in a normal html file its working fine.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/../resources/css/stylecreate.css" />
    <title>Festival erstellen</title>


    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script th:inline="javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDuC0oHTI_mwfwW2HBiClpEuvSUKO7R8mg&amp;sensor=false"></script>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        function geocodePosition(pos) {
         geocoder.geocode({
         latLng: pos
         }, function(responses) {
            if (responses and responses.length > 0) {
            updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
         } else {
         updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
         }
        });
        }

        function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
            document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
            }

        function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
                 latLng.lat(),
                 latLng.lng()
                 ].join(', ');
            }

        function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
            document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
            }

        function initialize() {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
             zoom: 8,
             center: latLng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latLng,
             title: 'Point A',
              map: map,
                 draggable: true
             });

        // Update current position info.

        updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
         geocodePosition(latLng);

        // Add dragging event listeners.

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
          updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
          });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
         updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
         updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
         });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
         updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });
        }

        // Onload handler to fire off the app.

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                 </script>


    </head>
<body>

    <div th:id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div th:id="infoPanel">
<b>Marker status:</b>
<div th:id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
<b>Current position:</b>
<div th:id="info"></div>
<b>Closest matching address:</b>
<div th:id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are using chrome, any errors in the console?

Comment: yes its showing "SensorNotRequired". i'll quickly try it without sensor. thank you!

Comment: that is a warning. That is not related to this issue.

Comment: could you do view page source and copy-paste it here?

Comment: now its showing an uncought syntax error because of an unexpected identifier in this line(27): if (responses and responses.length > 0) {

Comment: okay i think i got it. i just had to use cdata markers because of thymeleaf.
it works just like this:

<script>
   // <![CDATA[
       script here
   // ]]>
</script>

and because we are using html it has to be commented out.
thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that `<div th:id="mapCanvas"></div>` is rendering `<div id="mapCanvas"></div>` correctly.

If that's the case, are you setting the `mapCanvas` div's width and height inside stylecreate.css? Empty divs usually have 0 height, so the map won't show up. You must always set a height on the `<div>` explicitly [[1]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Map_DOM_Elements).

Add the following lines in your CSS:

```
#mapCanvas {
   width: 200px;        
   height: 200px;
}
```